# Why is permission needed when running a script a different way?

Tags: shell, terminal

I have a python script that when I run in terminal:

```
py filename.py
```

That works fine. But with this style:

```
./filename.py
```

I get Permission denied error. Any idea why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `./filename.py` it executes the script.

When you do `py filename.py` the `py` program reads in your `filename.py` and runs.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that python itself has -x (executable) rights, but filename.py does not

Answer (score 3):

Your file needs to be marked as executable. You can see how its current permissions with [`ls(1)`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ls1.html) and change its permissions with [`chmod(1)`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/chmod1.html):

```
ls -l filename.py
chmod a+x filename.py
```

You will also need to make sure that the first line of your script has the [hashbang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) correctly:

```
#!/usr/bin/py
# the rest of your script...
```

Comment: Great answer, more than I asked. However, that hashbang I had to use was /usr/bin/python or /usr/bin/evn python.

Answer (score 1):

You have three types of permissions in posix compiliant systems: read, write and execute. You simply don't have rights to execute the script. In order to add permissions you have to call something like:

`chmod +x filename.py`

You have to remember that `./filename.py` won't execute your Python script even if you will add execution rights (if you don't have `#!/usr/bin/py` at the beginning). Python scripts need to be executed in an interpreter - not as a standalone application.